# SQL DATA COMPARE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables in which all columns are same. Below is the script with data.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_Prices_2]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [State] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MajorRegion] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ProductGroup] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PriceToRetailer] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [PriceToAgent] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [PriceToDistributor] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [PriceToAdmin] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Tbl_Prices_2] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Prices_2] ON

INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Prices_2] ([ID], [State], [MajorRegion], [ProductGroup], [PriceToRetailer], [PriceToAgent], [PriceToDistributor], [PriceToAdmin]) VALUES (1, N'Assam', N'ABC', N'AIRTEL', CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(3.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(2.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(3.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Prices_2] ([ID], [State], [MajorRegion], [ProductGroup], [PriceToRetailer], [PriceToAgent], [PriceToDistributor], [PriceToAdmin]) VALUES (2, N'Bihar', N'XYZ', N'IDEA', CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(4.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(2.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(3.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Prices_2] ([ID], [State], [MajorRegion], [ProductGroup], [PriceToRetailer], [PriceToAgent], [PriceToDistributor], [PriceToAdmin]) VALUES (3, N'Goa', N'PQR', N'AIRCEL', CAST(2.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(5.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(4.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(6.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Prices_2] OFF

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_Prices_1]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [State] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [MajorRegion] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ProductGroup] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PriceToRetailer] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [PriceToAgent] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [PriceToDistributor] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [PriceToAdmin] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Tbl_Prices_1] 
      PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Prices_1] ON
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Prices_1] ([ID], [State], [MajorRegion], [ProductGroup], [PriceToRetailer], [PriceToAgent], [PriceToDistributor], [PriceToAdmin]) VALUES (1, N'Assam', N'ABC', N'AIRTEL', CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(2.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(3.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Prices_1] ([ID], [State], [MajorRegion], [ProductGroup], [PriceToRetailer], [PriceToAgent], [PriceToDistributor], [PriceToAdmin]) VALUES (2, N'Bihar', N'XYZ', N'IDEA', CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(1.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(2.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(3.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Prices_1] ([ID], [State], [MajorRegion], [ProductGroup], [PriceToRetailer], [PriceToAgent], [PriceToDistributor], [PriceToAdmin]) VALUES (3, N'Goa', N'PQR', N'AIRCEL', CAST(6.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(3.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(4.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(6.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Prices_1] OFF
```

I need to compare for prices for each state and MajorRegion wise. I requires the below output:

```
TableName      ID    State   MajorRegion ProductGroup  Col_Difference   Value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tbl_Prices_1   1     Assam   ABC         AIRTEL          PriceToAgent     1
Tbl_Prices_2   1     Assam   ABC         AIRTEL          PriceToAgent     3 
Tbl_Prices_1   1     Goa     PQR         AIRCEL          PriceToRetailer  2
Tbl_Prices_2   1     Goa     PQR         AIRCEL          PriceToRetailer  3
```

Here `Col_Difference` shows the column name.

Comment: First Thnig first Try to avoid the names of any brand ,entity in your examples.. like  here you have used 'Airtel','Aircel'

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'Tbl_Prices_1' as [tableName], Tbl_Prices_1.ID, 
       'PriceToAgent' as [Col_Difference], Tbl_Prices_1.PriceToAgent
  from Tbl_Prices_1 
  join Tbl_Prices_2 
    on Tbl_Prices_2.ID = Tbl_Prices_1.ID
   and Tbl_Prices_2.PriceToAgent <> Tbl_Prices_1.PriceToAgent
union 
select 'Tbl_Prices_2' as [tableName], Tbl_Prices_2.ID, 
       'PriceToAgent' as [Col_Difference], Tbl_Prices_2.PriceToAgent
  from Tbl_Prices_2 
  join Tbl_Prices_1 
    on Tbl_Prices_2.ID = Tbl_Prices_1.ID
   and Tbl_Prices_2.PriceToAgent <> Tbl_Prices_1.PriceToAgent
```

...

Comment: Thanks, Suppose I have 100 cloumns in the 'Tbl_Prices_1' and 'Tbl_Prices_2' table then I need to union 100 times?

Comment: Boo hoo.  That should take all of 10 minutes.